# Search query string from array list of string of different objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to search a query string against the array of string stored in array of all the objects presents

my database structure looks like this

```
[0: 
     destination: ......
     name: ......
     name_list: [""some place", "some place 2", "some place3"]
1:
    destination: ......
    name: ......
    name_list: [""some place4", "some place 5", "some place3"]
2:
    destination: ......
    name: ......
    name_list: [""some place56", "some place 34", "some place3"]

and so on .... 
]
```

let's say

I want to get all the objects whose name_list array contains string "someplace3" but the query i will receive might only be "place3", since user might not know the complete or exact name. I can't figure how to search, I'am using expressjs module to search in my mongodb database like:

```
route.find({name_list: "place3"}, function(err, routes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    routeTosend = routes;
});
```

but obviously I am not getting any results, but if i search exactly like someplace3 it returns all the objects.

I am completely new to database hence mongodb as well, if anyone can help would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) provided by mongodb. You can do something like this

```
route.find({"name_list": {$regex : /.*places3.*/}}, function(err, routes) {
   if (err) throw err;
   routeTosend = routes;
});
```

To use variable inside regex you have to create regex object from a string using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor

```
var query= "place"; 
regx = new RegExp('.*' + query + '.*','i');

route.find({"name_list": regx}, function(err, routes) {
   if (err) throw err;
   routeTosend = routes;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, worked perfectly, but can i pass variables as well, inside regex expression ?

Comment: to use variable inside regex you have to create regex object from a string using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor something like this `{"name_list" : new RegExp(your_reg_variable)}`

Comment: something like, 
`var myquery = "place";
{"name_list" : new RegExp(myquery )}` 
but it's not working can you please help me out here.

Comment: try to concatenate pattern either in myquery variable or inside constructor

Comment: yep, got it, with `        var query= "place";
        regx = new RegExp('.*' + variable + '.*','i');`, thanks for the help, can you please update the answer with this as well.